# Smart positioning for overlapping labels in scatter plots for D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatterplot following the general guidelines:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Cengiz Ünder",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 1189,
    "minutes_played": "1702",
    "total_available_minutes": 2430,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1800
  },
  {
    "name": "Yusuf Yazici",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1343,
    "minutes_played": "1607",
    "total_available_minutes": 2070,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1620
  },
  {
    "name": "Okay Yokuslu",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 1058,
    "minutes_played": "1204",
    "total_available_minutes": 1980,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1800
  },
  {
    "name": "Enes Ünal",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 1404,
    "minutes_played": "1426",
    "total_available_minutes": 2430,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 2070
  },
  {
    "name": "Zeki Celik",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 1995,
    "minutes_played": "2175",
    "total_available_minutes": 2430,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 2070
  },
  {
    "name": "Emre Akbaba",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 447,
    "minutes_played": "537",
    "total_available_minutes": 990,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 810
  },
  {
    "name": "Kaan Ayhan",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 1499,
    "minutes_played": "1769",
    "total_available_minutes": 2160,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1890
  },
  {
    "name": "Deniz Türüc",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1182,
    "minutes_played": "1363",
    "total_available_minutes": 1620,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1260
  },
  {
    "name": "Hakan Calhanoglu",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 1646,
    "minutes_played": "2201",
    "total_available_minutes": 2700,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1890
  },
  {
    "name": "Abdülkadir Ömür",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1563,
    "minutes_played": "1798",
    "total_available_minutes": 2160,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1800
  },
  {
    "name": "Ozan Kabak",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 1354,
    "minutes_played": "1714",
    "total_available_minutes": 2700,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1890
  },
  {
    "name": "Irfan Can Kahveci",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1554,
    "minutes_played": "1755",
    "total_available_minutes": 2250,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1710
  },
  {
    "name": "Serdar Aziz",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 917,
    "minutes_played": "1397",
    "total_available_minutes": 2250,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1530
  },
  {
    "name": "Emre Kilinc",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1718,
    "minutes_played": "1748",
    "total_available_minutes": 1890,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1800
  },
  {
    "name": "Ertugrul Ersoy",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1620,
    "minutes_played": "1620",
    "total_available_minutes": 1890,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1800
  },
  {
    "name": "Hasan Ali Kaldirim",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1710,
    "minutes_played": "2353",
    "total_available_minutes": 2790,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1710
  },
  {
    "name": "Mert Günok",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1890,
    "minutes_played": "2100",
    "total_available_minutes": 2430,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1890
  },
  {
    "name": "Sinan Bolat",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 2250,
    "minutes_played": "2340",
    "total_available_minutes": 2340,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 2250
  },
  {
    "name": "Burak Yilmaz",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 760,
    "minutes_played": "760",
    "total_available_minutes": 1080,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 990
  },
  {
    "name": "Ömer Ali Sahiner",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1396,
    "minutes_played": "1396",
    "total_available_minutes": 1620,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1530
  },
  {
    "name": "Mert Müldür",
    "local_league": false,
    "league_minutes_played": 921,
    "minutes_played": "1639",
    "total_available_minutes": 2790,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1620
  },
  {
    "name": "Harun Tekin",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1530,
    "minutes_played": "2160",
    "total_available_minutes": 2520,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1710
  },
  {
    "name": "Mehmet Topal",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1224,
    "minutes_played": "1638",
    "total_available_minutes": 2430,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1530
  },
  {
    "name": "Tarkan Serbest",
    "local_league": true,
    "league_minutes_played": 1330,
    "minutes_played": "1700",
    "total_available_minutes": 2610,
    "total_available_league_minutes": 1980
  }
];

const margin = {top: 60, right: 60, bottom: 60, left: 60},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([0.5, 1]);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0.5, 1]);

const red = '#BC261A';
const yellow = '#F8D749';

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d => `%${Math.round(d*100)}`);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d => `%${Math.round(d*100)}`);

const svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height) + ')')
    .call(xAxis);
  
svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom/1.5) + ")")
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text('Tüm Maçlarda Oynama Yüzdesi (Sakat ve Cezalı Değilken)');

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
    .attr('y', 0 - margin.left)
    .attr('x', 0 - (height / 2))
    .attr('dy', '1em')
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .text('Lig Maçlarında Oynama Yüzdesi (Sakat ve Cezalı Değilken)');

svg.selectAll('.dot')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .attr('cx', d => x(parseInt(d['minutes_played']) / d['total_available_minutes']))
    .attr('cy', d => y(d['league_minutes_played'] / d['total_available_league_minutes']))
    .style('fill', d => d['local_league'] ? red : yellow)
    .style('stroke-width', 1)
    .style('stroke', d => d['local_league'] ? yellow : red);

const names = svg.selectAll('.names')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('text')
    .attr('x', d => {
      return x(parseInt(d['minutes_played']) / d['total_available_minutes']);
    })
    .attr('y', d => {
      return 20 + y(d['league_minutes_played'] / d['total_available_league_minutes'])
    })
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .style('font-size', 8)
    .text(d => d['name']);

const legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
    .data([red, yellow])
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend')
    .attr('transform', (d, i) => `translate(0, ${i*20})`);

  legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', 18)
      .attr('width', 18)
      .attr('height', 18)
      .style('fill', (d, i) => [red, yellow][i]);

  legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', 42)
      .attr('y', 9)
      .attr('dy', '.35em')
      .style('text-anchor', 'start')
      .text((d, i) => ['Türkiye Ligi', 'Diğer Ligler'][i]);
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,500,600,700');

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id='chart' width="600" height="600"></svg>
```

As you can see, there are some labels overlapping with other labels and also scatter points. I have looked into Force Layout but sadly could not find a proper solution for static visualizations. This has been a pain for me for a long time, and it is interesting to me that there are no solutions published (at least I could not find one) online for such a common case.

[How a simple solution looks like for ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAqin.png)

I will post a solution if I can manage to come up with one, but in the meantime, I'd be glad if someone already did it can help.

Comment: ggplot also not ideal: where is the Fiat

Comment: True, but it is better. [Another example](https://i.imgur.com/L7YAPkv.png), this time from Tableau.